# Image Classification+localization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

I am working on an Image Classification problem and my aim is to create a model where I can input the image, its class and the values for the bounding box(x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max). As of now I have worked with only image detection where I used ImageDataGenerator for loading my Images so this is something new to me.

In the book Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn,Keras & TensorFlow by Aurélien Géron, he briefly mentions Image classification and Localisation and provides a example model.

```
 base_model =keras.applications.xception.Xception(weights="imagenet",include_top=False)
 avg = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
 class_output = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(avg)
 loc_output = keras.layers.Dense(4)(avg)
 model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[class_output, loc_output])
 model.compile(loss=["sparse_categorical_crossentropy", "mse"], loss_weights=[0.8, 0.2],  optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

He also mentions that the data should be in the form of tuple

```
(images, (class_labels, bounding_boxes))
```

But as far as I know keras only accepts data in the form of array. So if any one could help me in understanding how the model should be designed and how one should feed inputs to the model to get the class of the image and the values of the bounding boxes as output.

Comment: I recommend using tfrecord. Here is a SO question and answer with links to a tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475410/loading-tf-records-into-keras

Answer (score 0):

Let the input data be the image and target values be the 4 coordinates i.e. coordinates of bounding box